# Django: empty formset in template

Tags: python, django

I'm building an application with Django and when using `InlineFormSet` with `ClassBasedViews` my `route_formset` is empty in template, but `form` is populated with data as it should be.

What am I doing wrong?

> View

```
class ReservationUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Reservation
    form_class = ReservationForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ReservationUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        return kwargs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles GET requests and instantiates versions of the form
        and its inline formsets.
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        route_formset = RouteFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  route_formset=route_formset))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance and its inline
        formsets with the passed POST variables and then checking them for
        validity.
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        route_formset = RouteFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and route_formset.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, route_formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, route_formset)

    def form_valid(self, form, route_formset):
        """
        Called if all forms are valid. Creates a Recipe instance along with
        associated Ingredients and Instructions and then redirects to a
        success page.
        """
        self.object = form.save()
        route_formset.instance = self.object
        route_formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, route_formset):
        """
        Called if a form is invalid. Re-renders the context data with the
        data-filled forms and errors.
        """
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  route_formset=route_formset))
```

> Template

```
{% for form in route_formset %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time / Place</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {{ form.time }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            {{ form.place }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

> Formset

```
RouteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Reservation, Stop, fields=('time','place'), extra=2)
```

> Result
>   [image]

So the formset should be populated with `Stops` but it is empty..

Comment: please add the relevant parts of your template and the class definition of the `RouteFormSet`.

Comment: @trixn updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize formset with instance to fill it with related data:

```
route_formset = RouteFormSet(instance=self.object)
```

Comment: @intelis Dont worry, I think we all know this feeling:)